# callback when required file's requirements have completely finished evaluating

Tags: requirejs

Sorry, I'm having a tough time wording this question.

Essentially I have a file includeme.js:

```
require('anotherjs.js', function() {
    console.log('yo, i should print before "hello"');
}
```

which is required by the following require function:

```
require('includeme.js', function() {
    console.log('hello, i should be printed second after "yo"');
});
```

I want ALL of includeme.js to be evaluated before my callback from 'require'ing includeme.js. So I want yo to be logged before hello. As is, includeme.js will be loaded, but then anotherjs.js will be loaded sync, meanwhile the callback with the hello log will be called, before anotherjs is finished being fetched and yo called.

Is there any way to have a callback that waits for a JS file to be fully evaluated with all requires returning?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use RequireJS as they recommend. Define the things you are requiring. 
SO in the case of my example:

```
require('anotherjs.js', function() {
    console.log('yo, i should print before "hello"');
}
```

SHould be:

```
define('anotherjs.js', function() {
     [...]
     return false;
}
```

You usually want to return something meaningful, but in my case I was just injecting controllers into my angular app, so I saw no reason to define. My guess is that require will wait for a "define", but won't wait for a "require". This makes sense considering "define" is generally per file and very entwined with requireJS, while require is simply a useful function.

So, don't be dumb like me, and make sure you define everything you plan to require. If what you are requiring prepares globals, then use shims. This is all recommended in the requireJS documentation.